# Lodash: Join values by given key

Tags: javascript, object, join, lodash

I am trying to search easy function on **Lodash.js** for joining values by given key or something...

**Example:**

```
const obj = {firstname : 'John', title: 'Mr.', lastname: 'Due'}
```

**Expected results:**

```
Mr. John Due
```

**Any function like** `_.join()` but better and I can do something like..

```
_.joinX(obj, ['title', 'firstname', 'lastname'], ' ')
```

---

Why not just...?

```
obj.title + ' ' + obj.firstname + ' ' + obj.lastname
```

Because sometimes my object is so long like... (And I will not give more variable)

```
obj.current.user.info.title + ' ' + obj.current.user.info.firstname + ' ' + obj.current.user.info.lastname
```

Comment: `let joinX = obj => obj.title + ' ' + obj.firstname + ' ' + obj.lastname; let fullName = joinX(obj);`. Saved yourself from using a 1mb+ lib with a oneliner

Comment: Thanks, I'm already included Lodash in my project and using many Lodash's functions there ;)

Comment: Then make a feature request, so that it'll be even bigger :P Sarcasm aside, I don't think it has such feature. To me it doesn't look common enough to implement it, so you'd be better off using the oneliner

Comment: @Adelin, Understand :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think I got it:**

```
const obj = {firstname : 'John', title: 'Mr.', lastname: 'Due'}
let name = _(obj).pick(['title', 'firstname', 'lastname']).values().join(' ')
console.log(name)
```

*Not really special function as I expected but have to run tho Lodash's functions a bit*

Answer (score 1):

You can port the following to Lodash.

```js
const joinByKeys = (obj = {}, props = [], separator = '') => {
    // empty array.
    let arr = [];
    // push props to array
    props.forEach(p => arr.push(obj[p]))
    // return the joined array.
    return arr.join(separator);
}


const obj = {firstname : 'John', title: 'Mr.', lastname: 'Due'}

console.log( joinByKeys(obj, ['title', 'firstname', 'lastname'], ' ') );
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like this not requesting to use Lodash :)

Comment: I don't see any reason for using lodash, plain JavaScript can do it. If you are using lodash in other places in your project, then you can port these into lodash functions.

Comment: Agreed, I just looking for if any Lodash's way :D

Comment: @l2aelba then my suggestion is, for further such requests, to exclude JS tag from the question.